# Selenium IE alert dissappears

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

On my page there is a delete button which upon clicking will show an alert along the lines of "are you sure" with the options "Ok" and "Cancel".

When running the selenium script in chrome the stand alert().accept(); works fine.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

However when running in Internet Explorer(11) the alert appears then instantly disappears before selenium can do anything with it.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and has any inclination to the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code before you handle Alert, It should work fine in Internet Explorer along with other Browsers.

```
WebDriverWait  Alert_test6 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Alert_test6.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

I am creating a wait object which will wait till alert gets visible. In your current case the script is running too fast then the actual browser navigation and that could be the reason.